Apache Camel - Split, Tokenize and Aggregate not completing when using exchange-factory pooled
I'm having an issue with an Apache Camel route after migrating to version 4.6.0. The problem is that the exchange is never set to done when exchange-factory is pooled instead of default value prototype, and the SPLIT_COMPLETE property always remains false. This causes the aggregation to never complete.
Here's my route definition:
from(direct("input"))
 .routeId("input-route")
 .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
 .unmarshal().mimeMultipart()
 .split().tokenize("\n").streaming()
 .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
 .completionSize(1000)
 .completionPredicate(exchangeProperty(Exchange.SPLIT_COMPLETE))
 .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
 .multicast().parallelProcessing()
 .to(direct("output"));

Expected behavior:
Using exchange-factory is pooled, the aggregator should complete when either the batch size is reached or when the SPLIT_COMPLETE property is set to true.
The exchange should be marked as done after processing.
Actual behavior:
The SPLIT_COMPLETE property is always false.
The exchange is never set to done.
The aggregation never completes.
The MulticastProcessor.MulticastTask#iterator keeps growing, finishes leading to OOM.
This issue started occurring after migrating to Apache Camel 4.6.0. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or know what might be causing this behavior?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can you try with Camel 4.8.0 first and report back. If still a problem you are welcome to create a JIRA ticket

@Claus, Thank you for your suggestion. I've followed your advice, but unfortunately, the issue remains present in Camel 4.8.0. As per your recommendation, I'll proceed with creating a JIRA ticket.

Okay thanks for checking
